# crystal report formula Search * 'Like'

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

[image]

> {Detail  A } Like '%*%'
>     {Detail  A } Like '***'

Can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK theres no possibility to check for an asterisk `*` using the `Like` operator in Crystal Reports.

But you can user the `InStr`-function instead:

```
Instr({@Detail A}, "*") > 0
```

The `InStr`-function will return the position of the first occurrence of the character "*" in the `Detail A`-formula.

Means, if the character is being found, the return value is `> 0`.